# Become fluent in a language without study it

Tags: language-acquisition

I ask me if It's possible become fluent in a language without study it. When You are 1/2  years old, you learn a languages without studying it. You need just to listen and listen.  So, Is it possible learn a language without study it and just read and listening it?
Examples, I'm 13 and I'm studying English for 4 years. I started to learn it watching cartoon, Anyway I studied it in school and I had some basics (like verb to have, to be, subject and a few things). 
Anyway, Is it possible learn a language without study it when you don't know anything in it? How to?

Comment: This question is about the language acquisition, not about the properties of the languages. So it better fits at [Language Learning.SE Beta](http://languagelearning.stackexchange.com/) site.

Comment: You can definitely become fluent in a language without formally studying it, but you'll need to immerse yourself in an environment where everyone only speaks that language. TV and movies and books can help, but you'll never be fluent without live practice.

Comment: If you're a child, yes, if not, then probably not. What other kind of answer would you expect?

Comment: @curiousdannii I had this speculative idea a few years ago—that perhaps childhood is not necessarily a state of the brain, but a set of *life circumstances* that are conductive to quick language acquisition, and perhaps it's possible to functionally recreate those circumstances later in life. But I can't think of how, short of being on an alien planet, completely dependent on a few critical life support systems, and having to make sense of the alien civilisation you've encountered. Maybe, just maybe, that would fire up the "first language" circuitry that the brain never actually retired.

Comment: Well there's a lot of debate over whether a critical period for language acquisition exists.